# SQL Query Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which I want to run a query against to pull out data to a csv file. The data needs to be sorted by username and I only want output of people created within the last seven days.

So far I can pull out the data that I need, but can't quite figure how to achieve the piece surrounding only the last seven days. My query looks like this at present;

```
SELECT
  user_name,
  created_date
FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user
WHERE user_name LIKE 'guest-%'
```

A line of the resulting output (once in the csv) looks like;

```
guest-12343,2016-09-20 19:57:50.347
```

Can anyone recommend how I might be able to adapt the statement to be more selective on with the data in the created_date column?

Comment: You need to add condition that your date is between `today` and `today - 6 days`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use created_date in your WHERE clause.  Now the question is how do you define "last seven days."  If you want 7 * 24 hours before now, it would be

```
SELECT user_name, created_date 
FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user 
WHERE user_name like 'guest-%' 
  AND created_date >= GETDATE() - 7
```

If you want your 7 day period to be 6 full days plus today, it would be:

```
SELECT user_name, created_date 
FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user 
WHERE user_name like 'guest-%' 
  AND created_date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 6)
```

Or if you want your 7 day period to be 7 full days not including today, it would be:

```
SELECT user_name, created_date 
FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user 
WHERE user_name like 'guest-%' 
  AND created_date >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 7)
  AND created_date < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

This is assuming created_date is storing dates in the server's timezone. If it has UTC dates, change GETDATE() to GETUTCDATE().

Answer (score 1):

**For getting data within 7 days** add this in your where clause

```
AND created_date >= DATEADD(day, -6, convert(date, GETDATE()))
```

**For Sorting with user name** add this @end

```
ORDER BY user_name
```

So final Query will be :

```
SELECT user_name, created_date FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user WHERE user_name like 'guest-%' created_date >= DATEADD(day, -7, convert(date, GETDATE())) ORDER BY user_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_name, created_date 
FROM DATABASENAME.dbo.tbl_user 
WHERE
    user_name like 'guest-%'
    AND Created_Date >= CAST(GETDATE() - 7 AS DATE)
ORDER BY user_name
```

Assuming you want from 12:01 AM 7 days ago and that Created_Date can never be greater than Now [Getdate()]